# Encountered a duplicated sql alias [col1] during auto-discovery of a native-sql query in spring boot 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have migrated my project from spring boot 2.x to spring boot 3.x and using hibernate 6.1.7

Entity

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ1")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ1", sequenceName="SEQ1", allocationSize=1)
    @Column(name = "COL_SK")
    private Long sk;
```

Serviceimpl

```
@PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private static final String CCN_LIST = "select c1 FROM CCN c1 where c1.ccnCode in (:ccnCdList)";
    
    @Override
    public List<CCN> findByCcnCdList(List<String> ccnCdList) {
        List<CCN> ccns = new ArrayList<CCN>();
        
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(ccnCdList)) {
            List<List<String>> ccnCdSubLists = ListUtils.partition(ccnCdList, 2000);

            Query query = entityManager.createQuery(CCN_LIST, CCN.class);
                                        
            for (List<String> ccnCdSubList : ccnCdSubLists) {               
                query.setParameter("ccnCdList", ccnCdSubList);
                ccns.addAll(query.getResultList());                             
            }           
        }
        
        return ccns;

    }
```

But i am getting an error

org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Encountered a duplicated sql alias [COL_SK] during auto-discovery of a native-sql query

Please note: above code working fine in spring boot 2.x

Comment: It might be helpful to show the rest of the fields from the entity class.

Comment: The code you wrote makes no sense. The error is about native queries, but you use the `createQuery` instead of `createNativeQuery` method. Nobody will be able to help you if you post wrong and confusing information.